# How to add bar buttons in a UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have created a `UIToolBar` and want to add three items in that like contact, date and message. I tried but i am not able to do that.Kindly help as i am new to `Objective C`. Here is my `"ViewController.m"`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 414, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *contact = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *message = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:contact,message, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
[items release];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: comment [items release]; and [toolbar release]; and try once. Let me know if it works..

Comment: commenting those lines does not make any difference..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Following code i added two  `UIBarButton` with **flexSpace**..
**you can add UIBarButton as you want**

```
UIToolbar *Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    Toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [Toolbar sizeToFit];

     NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    [flexSpace release];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Cancel)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done)];
    [barItems addObject:btnDone];

    [Toolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
```

**Following Method is call when tapped on bar Button**

```
-(void)Cancel
{
  // Write Code for Cancel Method
}

-(void)done
{
  // Write Code for Done Method
}
```

Comment: SO user wants button on UIToolbar and not Navigation Controller, read question properly.

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    myToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *contactBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(contact:)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

 UIBarButtonItem *dateBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(date:)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

 UIBarButtonItem *msgBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(message:)];

[myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexibleSpaceLeft, doneBtn, flexibleSpace, dateBtn, flexibleSpaceRight, msgBtn, nil]];
```