# Toolbar above Keyboard is not displaying on -- iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11

The toolbar above the keyboard is not showing up on iOS 11.0. It's working fine on <11.0 versions.

Here is my code of adding a toolbar. So what I should add to display it
on iOS 11.0:

```
UIToolbar* customToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];     
        customToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        customToolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+ Contact" 
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                    target:self 
                                    action:@selector(showPicker:)],
               [[UIBarButtonItem 
          alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
               target:nil 
               action:nil],
              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"- Contact" 
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                    target:self 
                                    action:@selector(HidePicker:)],
                               nil];
        [customToolBar sizeToFit];
        self.textView.inputAccessoryView=customToolBar;
```

Comment: have you tried using this on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704686/how-to-add-bar-buttons-in-a-uitoolbar

Comment: Actually problem is not with ToolBar, problem is with iOS update. I'm sure something must be added for supporting toolbar in iOS 11 & thats not out yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in iOS 11 beta, there is an issue with showing toolbars when not using default keyboard (for example datepicker, value picker). This could be solved by adding the following line to the pickerView: `pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Actually for my it was iOS 11 beta issue.

Comment: This issue is also in iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working for me, please try it:

```
customToolBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

It looks like a bug in ios 11.